# Unable to identify the source of runtime error

Tags: python-3.x

While solving the below linked problem in Hackerrank 
[Problem Statement on Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-minion-game/problem)

I came up with the following code:

```
def minion_game(s):
    st=[]
    ke=[]
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(i,len(s)):
            if(s[i]=='A' or s[i]=='E' or s[i]=='I' or s[i]=='O' or s[i]=='U'):
                ke.append(s[i:j+1])
            else:
                st.append(s[i:j+1])
    if(len(st)>len(ke)):
        print("Stuart",len(st))
    elif(len(ke)>len(st)):
        print("Kevin",len(ke))
    elif(len(st)==len(ke)):
        print("Draw")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = input()
    minion_game(s)
```

After I submitted my code, I got a Runtime Error as the result I am unable to identify the source of error in the code that is generating the Runtime Error. If possible can you help me rectify or this error.

If needed please clarify what more I need to add to make my post better and according to the guidelines of the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is crashing on a test case with a very long string as the input. Because your code is counting substrings by appending every possible substring to one list or another, instead of just keeping running totals of numbers of substrings, you're running into a memory error after a while.